# Clear all query credentials from ODBS connection when an Excel file launches

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to clear all query credentials from my ODBS connection when an Excel file launches.

The manual way to do this is: DATA -> GET `DATA -> DATA SOURCE SETTINGS -> CLEAR ALL PERMISSIONS.`

[image]

I tried:

```
Private Sub workbook_open()
    Dim MyCon As WorkbookConnection
    Dim ODBCMyCon As ODBCConnection

    For Each MyCon In ThisWorkbook.Connections
        Set ODBCMyCon = MyCon.ODBCConnection
        ODBCMyCon.SavePassword = False
    Next

    For Each MyCon In ThisWorkbook.Connections
        ODBCMyCon.connection.Refresh
    Next

    MsgBox ("Connection credentials are cleared")
End Sub
```

How can I automatically clear permissions?